# Today I updated my R studio program, and now my codes doesn't work anymore

Tags: r, dplyr

Yesterday my code worked properly but today it won't work after an update. I keep getting the message in the error that the N value is no longer in the data.

```
df %>%
   group_by(Branche, Contract, Algemene_indruk) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Algemene_indruk, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
   filter(onvoldoende != 0)
```

Dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)


df <- read_xlsx("dataset.xlsx")
```

[image]

Comment: is your dataset `df` correctly loaded ? what does head(df) return ?

Comment: yes df returns the excel data set

Comment: since `mtcars %>%
  group_by(vs, cyl) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = cyl, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))` works like a charm, you have tp provide data, e.g. insert the output of `dput(head(df, 10))` in your question

Comment: It looks like a package preference issue. if the same function is present in multiple packages, the user needs to provide the package name to use function from the correct package. use `dplyr::n()` in stead of `n()`